# How I can store line in PostgreSQL using Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, postgresql, flask

I have a problem. I'm building an application using Flask, database in PostgreSQL and Leaflet. In the application the user can draw a line by clicking on the map all points are added to array and create a line( all code in js) . I created a columns in database in Flask using SQLAlchemy. I wonder how I can store this road as a line in database? Does such a type exists in SQLAlchemy ?

Function in js

```
function clickonMap(event){
        dict = event.latlng
        coordintates.push(Object.values(dict))
        if(mymap.hasLayer(polyline)){
            polyline.remove()
        }
        mark = L.marker(event.latlng,{icon: markerIcon}).addTo(mymap);
        markers.push(mark)
        polyline = L.polyline(coordintates,{color: 'red'}).addTo(mymap)
```

Comment: you can keep it as normal string with list of numbers `(lat,long)`. And even JSON is normal string which you can save in any database or file. So if javascript can convert it to JSON (which means string) then you can send it to server and save in database. (PL: możesz stworzyć tekst z listą, która zwiera liczby `(lat,long)` - nawet JSON to tylko string z danymi, który możesz zapisać w bazie danych)

Comment: I don't know if I understand it well. I need to create a JSON column type in the database and added a points ? Or normal String type with list of points?

Comment: first in JavaScript you have to convert object(s) to string to send it to server. You can create list with points  `[(lat,long), ...]` or with more values `, [(lat,long, color, ...), ...]` or with dictionares `[{"lat": lat, "long": long}, ... ]` and `JavaScript` will convert it to string when you send it to server - and this string is JSON. On server you can keep it as string in database. If you will use it only to send it back to browser then string is enought. If you plan to search points in database then maybe it would be better to create column with JSON type.

Comment: it seems in your code you have it already as list in `coordintates` and probably it could be send as string to server. And server may keep it as string. If you send it back to browser then JavaScript should easy convert it back from string to list using [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: It seems I still dont understand. So i need to send `coordinates` using `XMLHttpRequest` to the server? And i need to create a String column in the database? When I will have this points in the database I want to create from them a line and add to map.

Comment: yes, you need `XMLHttpRequest` or modern `fetch()` to send `coordintates` from JavaScript to server - `JSON.stringify(coordinates)`. And keep it in database as string. And when you want to display it again (ie. next day) then you get string from database and you generate `HTML` with `JavScript` code which use `JSON.parse()` like `coordinates = JSON.parse(string_from_database)` and `L.polyline(coordinates, ...)`

Comment: I use: ```var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open('POST', 'mapaa', true);
    var msgjson = JSON.stringify(coordintates)
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    xhttp.send(msgjson);
    console.log(msgjson);```  and i want to display it in flask, but `data = request.get_json()` returns None.

Comment: I made minimal working code which send to Flask and it displays it . And it gets from Flask but still doesn't display on map.

Comment: Can you explain me how you did it ? Because I still dont know why it doesn't work for me ;/

Comment: I added all working code as answer. You can copy it to one file and run it. BTW: All browsers have `fetch()` which is simpler then `XMLHttpRequest()`

Answer (score 0):

Minimal working code which uses modern `fetch()` to send data from browser to Flask, and it keep it on list. Later you can load it back and it also use `fetch()` to get it from Flask.

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` only to make it simpler for test. Everyone can copy code to one file and test it.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>       
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>       
</head>

<body>

<div id="map" style="width:400px; height: 300px;"></div>   

<button onclick="save();">Save</button>
<button onclick="clean();">Clean</button>
<button onclick="load();">Load</button>

<script>

    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);
    
    var coordintates = [];
    var polyline = [];
    
    function clickOnMap(event){
        latlng = event.latlng;
        
        coordintates.push(Object.values(latlng));
        
        if(mymap.hasLayer(polyline)){
            polyline.remove();
        }
        
        // mark = L.marker(event.latlng, {icon: markerIcon}).addTo(mymap);
        // markers.push(mark);
        
        polyline = L.polyline(coordintates, {color: 'red'}).addTo(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', clickOnMap);

    function save() {
        // console.log(coordintates);
        
        fetch('/save', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(coordintates)
        });
    }
    
    function clean() {
        if(mymap.hasLayer(polyline)){
            polyline.remove();
            coordintates = [];
        }
        
        // console.log(coordintates);
    }

    function load() {
        fetch('/load')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
                
            coordintates = data;

            // console.log(coordintates);
            
            if(mymap.hasLayer(polyline)){
                polyline.remove();
            }
            
            polyline = L.polyline(coordintates, {color: 'red'});
            // console.log(polyline);
            polyline.addTo(mymap);
        });
    }
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
''')

database = []

@app.route('/save', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save():
    data = request.json 
    print('save:', data)
    database.append(data)
    return "OK"

@app.route('/load', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def load():
    if database:
        data = database[-1]
    else:
        data = []        
    print('load:', data)
    return jsonify(data)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run() #debug=True
```

Comment: I copy this `fetch()` to my code and it work.I load my map and click the points and when I click the end button I use `print(data)` in FLASK and I have this coords in console.I try to set this coords in `if 'form1' in request.form` and add it to the database to route field but in the database i recieve null.I need to set this coords somehow in form?

Comment: it sends as JSON data, not FORM data - and in Flask I use `request.json` instead of `request.form`

Comment: I understand but i gave `print(data)` before `'form1' in request.form` and in console i have this data but when I want to display data in `if` i have null. I want to add coords to the database but the row is created in `if`.

Comment: in my code `data = request.json` and you should do `'form1' in request.json`. You can't have both `json` and `form`

Comment: So how i can send data from form and coordinates to the database if i can't do that like this?

Comment: send all as JSON. create `{data_from_form: ... , coordinates: ...}` OR send all as FORM - create `new Form()`, add elements from form, and coordinates.

Comment: It work !! I sent data as JSON and now everything is fine. Thank you very much !